# Is it possible to pass db name as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have about 100 sites built in a cms, each with its own database. Each database has the same tables.

My stored procedure needs to select all of the pages in a database given a sitename.

Below I am trying to pass the database name as a parameter, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
...
@site nvarchar(250)

AS

SELECT *
FROM @site..cmsDocument
WHERE published = 1
```

Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT @dbname = quotename(dbname)
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT ... FROM ' + @dbname + '.dbo.tablename WHERE ...'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, ...
```

Refs:

[sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Using dynamic SQL with distributed query notation is the only way you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the database in the connection string:

Data Source=myServerAddress;**Initial Catalog=myDataBase**;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Answer (score 1):

Almost no DBMSes allow you to use a parameter in this manner. Build a dynamic query via concatenation and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the undocumented stored procedure sp_MSforeachdb:
sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT * FROM ?..table_name_here'

Answer (score 0):

If the query / procedure is being executed from a .NET application, you can also programmatically change the database of the connection object (VB.NET):

```
Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM cmsDocument WHERE published = 1", GetDatabaseConnection(ServerName))
     da.SelectCommand.Connection.ChangeDatabase("Foobar")
End Using
```